# how to disable "login with Google/Facebook" on wix member site

Tags: velo

I'm afraid of the answers i'm going to get. this might not be possible. But is there a way to force wix members to sign in with email/password as opposed to letting them sign in with the facebook/google option?

I have a client that has a site that is very data heavy. the user needs to be forced thru the signup form so we can collect all the data to make the API's run correctly. If they simply sign in with google/facebook, they will have a wix member account. But since they bypassed the signup form, none of the data that makes the site what it is will be there, resulting in a horrible user experience full or errors and dysfunction.

can anyone tell me how to disable the option (on my wix members sign in page) to sign in with facebook/google, forcing them to use the email/password option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After calling Wix support:

If you use a standard sign up form you can disable the socials sign in. For some reason it doesnt show when you use a custom form. Just switch it to standard form,  disable socials sign in, then switch back to custom form.  This will work

Answer (score 1):

From the Wix Editor:

1. Click on the "Pages" ribbon
2. Click "Signup & Login
3. Member Signup Form (Default)
4. Social & Community
5. Flip the toggles to disable the respective Facebook or Google login option

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also just delete the social login buttons while editing the custom login page. That seemed to sidestep the 'default' and 'custom' login issues described in an earlier post.